# How do I change the screen working area using SHAppBarMessage in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I've been looking at the MSDN article for visual C++ and it looks kind of intimidating:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177(VS.85).aspx

All the other articles that I've been linked to 404. 
Basically, I'm creating a desktop application toolbar that changes the working area of the screen when it's docked so that no maximized windows cover it. System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea is read only so I can't really use it for anything other than being able to determine what area of the screen is not being taken up by the docked toolbar.

Please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind, found a good article here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx?fid=14729&select=1796941#xx1796941xx